# second time submit form with info changed but the action in server didnt get the request

Tags: java, spring, web

just a login HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>测试的登录页面</title>
<link href="css/mui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">

</head>
<body>
<header class="mui-bar mui-bar-nav">
    <h1 class="mui-title">登录</h1>
</header>
    <div class="mui-content">
        <form id='login-form' class="mui-input-group" action="/front/login">
            <div class="mui-input-row" style="padding-right: 14px;">                
                <input name="phone" type="text" style="width: 66%;" class="mui-input-clear mui-input" placeholder="请输入你的手机号">                           
            </div>      
            <div class="mui-content-padded">
                <button id='login' class="mui-btn mui-btn-block mui-btn-primary" type="submit" >登录</NOtton>     
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="js/mui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the action is here

```
package com.neu.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import com.neu.beans.Userlist;
import com.neu.service.FrontCheckService;

@Controller
public class FrontLoginHandler {
    @Autowired
    private  FrontCheckService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/front/login")     
    public  String frontlogin(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //请求和响应的信息都不应该被存储在对方的磁盘系统中； 
        System.out.println("....servlet....frontlogin()......");
        System.out.println("....servlet....frontlogin()......");
        System.out.println("....servlet....frontlogin()......");
        System.out.println("....servlet....frontlogin()......");
        System.out.println("....servlet....frontlogin()......");
        //从数据库查找是否存在这样一个手机号的用户
        //如果存在那么就取出来 返回
        //如果不存在那么就 写入一个
        String phone=request.getParameter("phone");         
        if(service.check(phone)==null)
        {
            Userlist user=new Userlist();
            user.setTel(phone);         
            user.setUname(phone);
            user.setOpenid(phone);
            user.setUserimg("default.jpg");
            adduser(user);
            System.out.println(user.getTel());
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            System.out.println("存入session成功！");
            return "forward:index.html";
            //如果为空 捏造一个用户 返回 并 写入数据库
        }
        else
        {
            Userlist user= service.check(phone);
            System.out.println(user.getTel());
            HttpSession session=request.getSession();            
            session.setAttribute("user", user);
            System.out.println("存入session成功！");
            return "forward:index.html";
            //如果不为空 那就将返回的对象返回
        }
    }

    public  void adduser(Userlist user)
    {
        String phone= user.getTel();
        service.insert(phone);        
    }
}
```

the question is that when I input a phone number for the first time, login is successful, and it get's the right username . and when I surf the page again and submit with another phone number. its ok .but the third time with another phone number login the username is named before.
I check the eclipse console find the third time request didn't send to the action, because of the several "System.out.println()" didn't print.
the get name page is a page with ajax to get another action to return the "user" attribute of session.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a browser-caching issue here. Try disabling the cache for your particular request with e.g.:

```
response.addHeader("Cache-Control", CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());
```

Comment: i did that before and it couldnt work.but i do it now ,it works. thanks .and it must be the cache issue,because when i F12 ->network->Disable cache ,all works.but why the cache used in the third time submit,not the second time(user 1 submit,user 2submit,user 3 submit ,it works...but user 1 submit ,user 1 submit ,user 2 submit ,it broken and the third time info submitted is different from first and second ,why it use cache the third time.... wired

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your application design.

1. Use Post method to post information from client side to server.

   ```
   <form id='login-form' class="mui-input-group" action="/front/login" method="post">
   ```
2. You are not invalidating the session created by first or second user.Session management is spring is necessary to handle login from multiple users.
3. Use cache control headers at your global configuration or on your jsp / html page. though some browser doesnt honor the headers setting.

Comment: thanks very much.this project actually is my friend's ,i have advise him your second and third advise before asking this question ,but the third is doesnt work because the page that it returns to uses webview,and the cache didnt exsist index.html(i guess so),the second advise ,because he didnt want to do.....so i ask tthe question here,it looks "response.addHeader("Cache-Control", CacheControl.noCache().getHeaderValue());" work after he add this again ,the first time he added ,it didnt work .....wired.after all ,thanks